# Twitter OAuth Send Status Update Not Working

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, status, reply

Why is this code not working? I need it to get the latest tweets for the search tag dog and then submit a status update with a reply to the user who sent the tweet with the search tag dog. I am using Abraham's twitteroauth found here: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/downloads

```
   <?php
require_once('twitteroauth.php');

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMERKEYHERE');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'SECRET HERE');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'TOKENHERE');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', 'TOKENSECRETHERE');

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$twitter->host = "http://search.twitter.com/";
$search = $twitter->get('search', array('q' => 'dog', 'rpp' => 5));

$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";
foreach($search->results as $tweet) {
    $status = '@$tweet->from_user Here my reply would go';
    $twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $status));
}
?>
```

I have entered my consumer key, secret and tokens but removed them here.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to be half-useless here as I haven't worked with TwitterOAuth in a while, but IIRC if you print out the `$twitter` variable it should have a field that tells you the last error received from twitter.com

Comment: That gives me the error: Object of class TwitterOAuth could not be converted to string

Comment: It gives me errors and shows connection timeout with the https://api.twitter.com/1/ This: object(TwitterOAuth)#1 (13) { ["http_code"]=> NULL ["url"]=> NULL ["host"]=> string(26) "https://api.twitter.com/1/" ["timeout"]=> int(30) ["connecttimeout"]=> int(30) ["ssl_verifypeer"]=> bool(false) ["format"]=> string(4) "json" ["decode_json"]=> bool(true) ["http_info"]=> NULL ["useragent"]=> string(25) "TwitterOAuth v0.2.0-beta2" ["sha1_method"]=> object(OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1)#2 (0) { } ["consumer"]=> object(OAuthConsumer)#3 (3) { ["key"]=> string(22)

Comment: And then it shows all the consumer key etc.

Comment: Set `$response = $twitter->post(...);` and then `var_dump($response);` That will print any error returned from Twitter. If you are getting a connection timeout check you can actually connect to api.twitter.com and there isn't a firewall blockin connections.

Comment: it's telling me it's read-only but it isn't..

Comment: I fixed it :3 The oath was read only so recreated the access token.

Comment: Now getting this error: Could not authenticate with OAuth.

Comment: Fixed that now, but now I am getting this returned from var_dump: NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Comment: @abraham (Hense the number of times it says NULL is 5 and I'm trying to send out 5 tweets).

Comment: Try setting `$twitter->decode_json = FALSE;` after you set the host back to the api.twitter.com. I'm thinking that maybe Twitter is returning a non JSON response that can't be parsed. Please also update your code above with the current state you are using.

Comment: Now the var_dump($response); returns nothing but no tweets are posted.

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter [search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) is separate from the REST API and doesn't require authentication.  So using OAuth probably won't work.

Comment: It returns the search results fine, so that's working as I can echo them. The only thing that isn't working is the posting of the status update.